# Google Tag Assistant listed as traffic source

Tags: google-analytics-4

In GA4 I keep getting traffic whose source is identified as "tagassistant.google.com".  However, I'm not in the tag manager in my browsers and the traffic duration is longer than google just querying my page with a bot.

Is this normal or should I be looking at my GA4 setup to see if I've got something wrong?